# Filter Firebase Data SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

This code adds all the data in a single array. In HomeViev I use to Foreach and I added to data to list. But I have to split the data in two. status collection has two type "active" and "closed" but I don't know how can I filter

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Firebase

let dbCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Signals")

class FirebaseSession : ObservableObject {

    @Published var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}
    @Published var data = [Signal]()

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<FirebaseSession, Never>()
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?


    func listen () {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print("Got user: \(user)")
                self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
                self.readData()
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func readData() {
        dbCollection.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }else {
                print("read data success")
            }

            documentSnapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { i in
```

// Read real time created data from server

```
            if i.type == .added {
                let id = i.document.documentID
                let symbol = i.document.get("symbol") as? String ?? ""
                let status = i.document.get("status") as? String ?? ""
                self.data.append(Signal(id: id, symbol: symbol, status: status))
            }
```

// Read real time modify data from server

```
            if i.type == .modified {
                self.data = self.data.map { (eachData) -> Signal in
                    var data = eachData
                    if data.id == i.document.documentID {
                        data.symbol = i.document.get("symbol") as! String
                        data.status = i.document.get("status") as? String ?? ""
                        return data
                    }else {
                        return eachData
                    }
                }
            }
```

// When data is removed...

```
            if i.type == .removed {
                let id = i.document.documentID
                for i in 0..<self.data.count{
                    if self.data[i].id == id{
                        self.data.remove(at: i)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states

> But I have to split the data in two

I assume that means two arrays; one for active and one for closed.

```
var activeData = [...
var closedData = [...
```

There are a couple of ways to do that

1) 
Query Firestore for all status fields equal to active and load those documents into the active array and then another query for status fields equal closed and load those in the the closed array

2)
I would suggest a simpler approach

```
if i.type == .added {
   let id = i.document.documentID
   let symbol = i.document.get("symbol") as? String ?? ""
   let status = i.document.get("status") as? String ?? ""

   if status == "active" {
      self.activeData.append(Signal(id: id, symbol: symbol, status: status))
   } else {
      self.closedData.append(Signal(id: id, symbol: symbol, status: status))
   }
}
```

and do the same thing within .modified and .removed; identify the status so the code will know which array to remove it from.

EDIT:

Based on a comment

> I don't know how to query this codes.

I am providing code to query for signals that are *active*. This code will return only active signals and as signals become active, inactive etc, this will modify a *signalArray* to stay in sync with the data.

```
let dbCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Signals")
let query = dbCollection.whereField("status", isEqualTo: "active").addSnapshotListener( { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) {
            let signalToAdd = Signal(withDoc: diff.document)
            self.signalArray.append(signalToAdd)
        }
        if (diff.type == .modified) {
            let docId = diff.document.documentID
            if let indexOfSignalToModify = self.signalArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.signal_id == docId} ) {
                let signalToModify = self.signalArray[indexOfSignalToModify]
                signalToModify.updateProperties(withDoc: diff.document)
            }
        }
        if (diff.type == .removed) {
            let docId = diff.document.documentID
            if let indexOfSignalToRemove = self.signalArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.signal_id == docId} ) {
                self.signalArray.remove(at: indexOfSignalToRemove)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Note that my Signal Class has an initializer that accepts a QueryDocumentSnapshot to initialize it as well as a .updateProperties function to update its internal properties.

Comment: Thank you Jay, I tried to try the first way but I didn't. I try your second way but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @John Both options work very well for us, with the second option being simpler. Saying 'it doesn't work' doesn't really tell us what doesn't work. Can you perhaps update your question showing the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Sory @Jay your solutions are working very good, thank you very much. Problem was about database rules. Can you help me for to .modified and .removed?

Comment: @John Sure... The code in .modified is a little strange... You kinda need to do there what your did in .deleted. You need to locate the matching item that was modified and then update the field with the new data. If you do that, then you can use the same format I used in the .added section except that if it changes from active to closed, you'll need to remove it from the added array. Before I update the answer, do you really need two separate arrays? One for active and one for closed or can you keep them in the same array and use other code to filter for active and closed Signals?

Comment: Hi @Jay, thank you very much for your time. No, absolutely no need to separate arrays. Actually, I tried to solve it with a query in a single array, but I couldn't.

Comment: @John Ok, then help me out. In your original question you said you needed to *split the data in two* so that's what I did in my answer. If you don't need to split it and it can all be stored in a single array then what's the actual problem you're having? The .modified code is a little odd in the question so I can help with that but maybe I am not understanding what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Sorry for the my wrong expression @Jay. The problem is I don't know how to query this codes.

Comment: @John Ah. ok. Will get you an answer in the morning.

Comment: @John I updated the answer with a query. I hope that's what you needed.

Comment: Hey @Jay Thank you very much for sparing time and response. That's all I need. I don't know how to thank you enough